# Inverse modulo $2$ binomial transform of generalised A284005

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, recurrences

Let $m \geqslant 1$ be a fixed integer.

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), $1$'s-counting sequence: number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$).

Let $f(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), exponent of highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, a.k.a. the binary carry sequence, the ruler sequence, or the $2$-adic valuation of $n$.

Let $\operatorname{tm}(n)$ be [A010060](https://oeis.org/A010060), Thue-Morse sequence: let $A_k$ denote the first $2^k$ terms; then $A_0 = 0$ and for $k \geqslant 0$, $A_{k+1} = A_k B_k$, where $B_k$ is obtained from $A_k$ by interchanging $0$'s and $1$'s.

Then we have an integer sequence given by
\begin{align}
a(0)& = 1\\
a(n)& = (m+\operatorname{wt}(n))a(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor)
\end{align}
Let
$$b(n) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{\operatorname{tm}(n-k)}(\binom{n}{k}\operatorname{mod} 2)a(k)$$
Then I conjecture that
\begin{align}
b(0)& = 1\\
b(2n+1)& = b(n) + (m-1)(-1)^{\operatorname{tm}(n)}\\
b(2n)& = b(n) + b(n-2^{f(n)}) + b(2n-2^{f(n)}) - (m-1)(m+1)^{f(n)+1}(-1)^{\operatorname{tm}(n)}
\end{align}

Is there a way to prove it?